# 2+ Regex arguments in findall() function using beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup, tags

I have following html code

```
    <table width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' class='blackbg textheadtitle'>
        <tr>
            <td width='41%' align='left'>Title</td>
            <td width='10%' align='left'>Year</td>
            <td width='10%' align='left'>Price</td>
                <table width='99%' border='0' cellpadding='1' class="normal">
        <tr>
            <td width='41%' align='left'><strong>Quatermass 2</strong></td>
            <td width='10%' align='left'>1957</td>
            <td width='10%' align='left'>&pound;295</td>


    <table width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' class='blackbg textheadtitle'>
        <tr>
            <td width='41%' align='left'>Title</td>
            <td width='10%' align='left'>Year</td>
            <td width='10%' align='left'>Price</td>
                <table width='99%' border='0' cellpadding='1' class="normal">
        <tr>
            <td width='41%' align='left'><strong>Ghostbusters</strong></td>
            <td width='10%' align='left'>1985</td>
            <td width='10%' align='left'>&pound;395</td>
```

I would like to pull out the years only

```
1957
1985
```

I have isolated the tags were "width": "10%" and i can insert a regular expression into the function to ignore the string 'Year' as follows

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

html = ['table.html']

with open("table.html", "r") as f:
    contents = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, "lxml")
for name in soup.find_all("td", {"width": "10%"}, string=re.compile(r'^(?!Year$)')):
    print((name).get_text())
```

Gives me

```
Price
1957
£295
Price
1985
£395
```

However if I wanted to ignore the string 'Price' and any string containing the '&pound', how could i do this? Can I enter another regex argument, perhaps by doing something like this?

```
for name in soup.find_all("td", {"width": "10%"},string=re.compile(r'^(?!Year$),'),(r'^(?!Price$)'),(r'^(?!&pound$)')):
    print((name).get_text())
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I would like to pull out the years only*

Just filter ***year*** values with respective regex pattern:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, "lxml")
for el in soup.find_all("td", {"width": "10%"}, string=re.compile(r'^\d{4}$')):
    print(el.get_text())
```